# Match Any Strings from Two Data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to match "any word in a string in Data Frame 1 matches any word in a string in Data Frame 2"? Using dplyr in R

```
---------- Data Frame 1 -------    --------- Data Frame 2
ID | Name             ZipCode      | Name_of_kin       ZipCode
1  | Peter Reeves     08011        | John Reeves       10212
2  | Peter Reeves     10212        | John Reeves       07052   
3  | Emily Sanchez    08012        | Roger James       08122
4  | Rico van Der     07052        | Moses van Fel     07052
5  | Monica SW        01010        | Monica South West 01010
6  | Michaelangelo    10212        | Michael           10212
```

I want to select rows where any word in Name_of_kin and ZipCode in data frame 1 matches any word in Name and Next of kin in data frame 2. I want to achieve this

```
ID | Name              | Name_of_kin       |  ZipCode
1  | Peter Reeves      | John Reeves       |  10212
4  | Rico van Der      | Moses van Fel     |  07052
5  | Monica SW         | Monica South West |  01010
6  | Michaelangelo     | Michael           |  10212
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

We can use a `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Name" = "Name_of_kin", "ZipCode"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
merge(data_frame_1,data_frame_2)
```